# Cannot find EC2 service using nodejs aws-sdk with browserify

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, browserify

I am using Node.js with browserify and I have setup AWS like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2b';
```

This works fine. An object is returned when I am printing to console.

However, when I do:

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
console.log(ec2);
```

It is failing to find EC2. I get `undefined is not a function`.

EC2 doesn't seem to exist. All the documentations direct me in this manner.

Comment: Try to use AWS.EC2() without SErvice, as decribed in doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html

Comment: Oh sorry. That's how I was using it and I'm still getting undefined is not a function. I was just trying different ways.

Comment: The error is happening in the browser? I don't think the node module will work like that. Instead, try using the AWS Javascript SDK for browsers

Comment: Figured it out. For anyone else wondering if you're using browseify an want additional AWS services you need to add it in the following format: `$ AWS_SERVICES=ec2,s3,dynamodb browserify index.js > browser-app.js`
Thanks everyone.

Comment: @ari If that's what solved your problem, please post it as an answer yourself, since it's not covered by the existing answers. :) Consider even marking the answer you post as accepted, since the answer you've currently marked as accepted doesn't seem to have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This script, it works for me with no problems.

```
// ec2script.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'});
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
console.log('EC2');
console.log(ec2);
```

just execute with

```
>node ec2script.js
```

This is the response I get.

```
EC2
{ config:
   { credentials:
      { expired: false,
        expireTime: null,
        accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        sessionToken: undefined },
     credentialProvider: { providers: [Object] },
     region: 'us-east-1',
     logger: null,
     apiVersions: {},
     apiVersion: null,
     endpoint: 'ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
     httpOptions: { timeout: 120000 },
     maxRetries: undefined,
     maxRedirects: 10,
     paramValidation: true,
     sslEnabled: true,
     s3ForcePathStyle: false,
     s3BucketEndpoint: false,
     computeChecksums: true,
     convertResponseTypes: true,
     dynamoDbCrc32: true,
     systemClockOffset: 0,
     signatureVersion: 'v4' },
  isGlobalEndpoint: false,
  endpoint:
   { protocol: 'https:',
     host: 'ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
     port: 443,
     hostname: 'ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
     pathname: '/',
     path: '/',
     href: 'https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' } }
```

If this doesn't work, check that you are using the correct access key and secret key.  IF the keys are correct and you are still haveing problems check to make sure the correct policies are in place for the keys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me a ton of time!